# How do I put space between my objects using GridBagLayout?

Tags: java, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I'm creating an application whereas I'm trying to put some distance between two text fields using GridBagLayout, but they keep appearing right underneath each other, even when I set the gridy variable to something greater than the previous text field.

I'm doing this within a panel, and on my main method, I'm calling the panel at the click of a button to display the panel on my main panel.

Here's my code for the addPanel method:

```
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.weighty = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    secondPanel.add(textField1, c);
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 30;
    secondPanel.add(textField2, c);
```

And on my main method:

```
    c.weightx = 1.0;
    c.weighty = 1.0;
    c.insets = new Insets(6, 6, 6, 6);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
    firstPanel.add(addPanel.getSecondPanel(), c);
```

After all this, the second text field remains right underneath the first one - even when i have specified `c.gridy = 30`.

My question is, how can I put some space between my two text fields using GridBagConstraints/Layout?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try adding borders on your panels? `panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));`

Comment: This doesn't do anything but add a border around my panel - the objects are still toe to toe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try specifying some insets when adding your text fields to `secondPanel`:

```
c.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.weighty = 0.5;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
secondPanel.add(textField1, c);
c.weightx = 0.5;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 30;
secondPanel.add(textField2, c);
```